# How to specify relative "Link to" so that navigation remains within nested route paths?

Tags: react-router

Ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7qabya?file=App.tsx

I am trying to create nested routes based on language param in the path URL

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/en">
          <Route index element={<Page text="Home Page!" />} />
          <Route path="first" element={<Page text="First Page!" />} />
          <Route path="second" element={<Page text="Second Page!" />} />
        </Route>
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={
            <Page
              text={"To begin, don't click anything. Change the path to /en"}
            />
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

I have trouble figuring out how to specify the "Link to={???}" such that it navigates relative to the language param.

In the below example,

- when I click Home, I expect it to stay on domain.com/en but actually it goes to domain.com
- when I click first, then second, I expect the path to be domain.com/en/second but actually the path becomes domain.com/en/first/second

```
const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="first">First</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="second">Second</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I see now, `Navigation` is rendered on a different sub-route. So you want these links to navigate into the `"/en"` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering the `Navigation` component on a sibling route to that where you want the links to navigate to. For this you'd need to specify relative paths into the sibling subroutes.

Example:

```
const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="../en">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="../en/first">First</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="../en/second">Second</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

I'm going to guess that `Navigation` was/is supposed to be rendered as part of a layout route for the `"/en"` sub-routes. You can use `"."` to refer to the current sub-directory.

Example:

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to=".">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="./first">First</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="./second">Second</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/en" element={<Layout />}> // <-- nav from here
      <Route index element={<Page text="Home Page!" />} />
      <Route path="first" element={<Page text="First Page!" />} />
      <Route path="second" element={<Page text="Second Page!" />} />
    </Route>
    ...
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

[image: Edit how-to-specify-relative-link-to-so-that-navigation-remains-within-nested-route]